# Greek Characters are invalid when reading a file in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a txt file with Greek text on a web server and i'm downloading grom my WP7 app using WebClient.
The problem is that the Greek characters coming as ?????????
Any suggetions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the encoding to UTF-8.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient ();
wc.Encoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: The problem now is coming when i read the file from the Isolated storage using StreamReader. Again the Greek characters are ??????

Comment: Try doing the same to stream reader or set UTF8 globally.If that does not work save the folder in utf8 format.

Other than these I do not know